Polars scan_ndjson() - TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
I'm trying to read a gzip jsonl file using scan_ndjson(). However, I encountered the error

"TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int"

despite passing a string. read_ndjson() works fine but I have memory issues so using a LazyFrame would be helpful.
Here's what I'm trying to do:
import gzip

with gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    df = pl.scan_ndjson(file.read(), ignore_errors=True))


The string that is accepted is for the file path, not file content. The TypeError comes because file.read() returns bytes which are then iterated over (giving you int) and passed to normalize_filepath()

Since scan_ndjson() only accepts filepaths, I created a temporary file.
import tempfile
import shutil

temporary_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', delete=False)

with gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') as file_in:
    shutil.copyfileobj(file_in, temporary_file)
    pl.scan_ndjson(
        temporary_file.name,
        ignore_errors=True,
        low_memory=True,
        rechunk=True
    )

temporary_file.close()
os.unlink(temporary_file.name)



scan functions expect a path that is on disk (we might support buffers later, but currently we don't). If you have in an in-memory buffer, you have to use read functions.
Try read_ndjson.

When I read the buffer, it returns a string, which should be accepted. Also, I'm using read_ndjson currently but I'm encountering memory issues just from trying to create dataframes so I'm trying to avoid using it.
